# libGDX - Strange Collision Behaviour

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection

I'm having some difficulty implementing very basic collision within libGDX. The update code for the "player" is as so:

```
private void updatePosition(float _dt)
{
    Vector2 _oldPos = _pos;

    _pos.add(_mov.scl(_dt*50));
    _bounds.setPosition(_pos.x-8, _pos.y-12);

    if(_game.getMap().checkCollision(_bounds))
    {
        System.out.println("Collision Detected");
        _pos = _oldPos;
        _bounds.setPosition(_pos.x-8, _pos.y-12);
    }
}
```

So, initially **_oldPos** is stored as the values of **_pos** position vector before applying any movement.

Movement is then performed by adding the movement vector **_mov** (multiplied by the delta-time * 50) to the position vector, the player's bounding rectange **_bounds** is then updated to this new position.

After this, the player's new bounding Rectangle is checked for intersections against every tile in the game's "map", if an intersection is detected, the player cannot move in that direction, so their position is set to the previous position **_oldPos** and the bounding rectangle's position is also set to the previous position.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, the player is able to travel straight through tiles, as seen in this image:
[image]

So what is happening here? Am I correct in thinking this code should resolve the detected collision?

What is strange, is that replacing

```
_pos = _oldPos;
```

with (making the same move just made in reverse)

```
_pos.sub(_mov.scl(_dt*50));
```

Yields very different results, where the player still can travel through solid blocks, but encounters resistance.

This is very confusing, as the following statement should be true:

```
_oldPos == _pos.sub(_mov.scl(_dt*50));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution for collision detection would be to have a Vector2 velocity, and every frame add velocity to position. You can have a method that tests if Up arrow key is pressed, add 1 (or whatever speed you would like) to velocity. And if down is pressed, subtract 1 (or whatever speed). Then you can have 4 collision rectangles on player, 1 on top of player, bottom, left, and right. You can say 
`if(top collides with bounds){
    if(velocity.y > 0){
      set velocity.y = 0.
   }
}`

And do the same for down, left and right (eg... for bottom, make sure to test if(velocity.y < 0) instead of if(velocity.y > 0).

**EDIT:** You code is not working because you set oldPos = pos without instantiating a new Vector2. Which means when you add onto pos, it also changes oldPos. So say oldPos = new Vector2(pos);

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks. So if I set a variable equal to another, it will "track" it real-time?

Comment: @W.H Yes, when you set an object equal to another without using new, it points to same memory as the object you set it equal to. Which means both objects are pointers to the same data.

Answer (score 0):

try to test future position before move. If collision, don't move.

Comment: Exactly the same result, unfortunately:
[image](http://puu.sh/nTO2Z/70a13ec93e.png)